# Can we read data from multiple tables at a time using tOracleInput

Tags: talend

Can we read data from multiple tables at a time using tOracleInput?
On talend

need answer.

Answer (score 0):

Probably by using the tParallelize component if you have subscription:
https://help.talend.com/r/en-US/7.3/orchestration/tparallelize-standard-properties